# General group theory book with exercise solutions

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book on group theory with approximately the same level and scope of "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups" by Joseph J. Rotman for which complete or partial exercise solutions exist (be it in the form of an official solutions manual or floating around on the internet). I need this for self study, Rotman is very readable and most exercises seem to be doable but see little point in attempting the more difficult ones if there is no way for me to double check my solutions (except maybe posting here).

Is there such a book?

Comment: Had a look at Schaum's Outlines?

Comment: That actually doesn't look too bad. I have never read one of the books in that series and had always assumed those were all less rigorous than other textbooks. Could I replace Rotman by that one completely or would it be advisable to read both? (I mainly need a good understanding of group theory fundamentals in order to go on and read texts on computational group theory).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have either book in front of me, so I can't really compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for another textbook, maybe just look for a problem book like John Dixon's *Problems in Group Theory*. Looking at the contents page of Rotman, it seems that there is some overlap in topics (normal series, Sylow theorems) and solutions are at the end.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, the problems also seem challenging so I think I'll try to get a copy of this one.